# adding data to a List and display it in a grid

Tags: android, list, listview, gridview

I'm getting a little confused about how to get data to display it in a grid or multicolumn listview. 
Here is the list I created from a datasource;

I have a problem getting it into the grid.

Thanks for any help.

```
  private List<OReady> pOrders;

  OReady rOrders = new OReady();
  rOrders.setNumber("123");
  rOrders.setQty("5");
  rOrders.setAmount("9.00");
  pOrders.add(rOrders);

 gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
 gridView.setAdapter(new OrdersAdapter(this, pOrders));
```

This part is giving me an error and any of the eclipse suggestions just create more errors.

this is my Ordersadapter.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
 public class OrdersAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
 private final Activity activity;
 private final List orders;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public OrdersAdapter(Activity activity, List objects) {
        super(activity, R.layout.pickup , objects);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.orders = objects;  
 }
```

Comment: A List is just an interface so it only defines methods not an implementation. ArrayList is an implementation of list and is generally the most common to use. Do you have a source for why you think it's not recommended?

Comment: Read the tutorials at `developer.android.com`.

Comment: When I was searching for ArrayList in Stackoverflow, there was a comment saying that ArrayList was only there for backward comparability and you should use List<T>. I did read the tutorial at developer.android.com and I still have no idea how to get the data into the ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great link that I used to create my list views. I think it will help you out a lot.

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Aside from that, yes, you would want to create a class to store the data. The tutorial above will hopefully answer all your questions.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but my problem is how to copy the data into the arraylist.

Comment: You copy the data like you would with any object. You use "setter" methods. It would really help if you posted the code that you are using.